Why is there no Synonym of the Day for October 9 2022?
This is bizarre. Today October 9th, we are getting today's Word of the Day at https://www.dictionary.com/e/word-of-the-day/, but we are not getting today's Synonym of the Day at https://www.thesaurus.com/e/synonym-of-the-day/. We are only able to see yesterday's Synonym of the Day ("posit"). I cannot understand what happened to today's Synonym of the Day (October 9th)?
Note: I wanted to ask this at the sister site: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, but that site currently does not have tags about dictionary.com and thesaurus.com, so I have to ask here instead.

This question is not suitable here.

@RohitGupta Where can I ask this?

webapps is probably the place. It doesnt matter if there is no tag for it.
